# Limit of the error of an approximation to the inverse function of $\frac{I_{n/2}(x)}{I_{n/2-1}(x)}$

Tags: limits, approximation, inverse-function, bessel-functions

Given $r$ computed as the "mean resultant vector length" from a sample from the [von Mises–Fisher distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mises%E2%80%93Fisher_distribution) in $n$ dimensions, the $\kappa$ solving
$$r=A_n(\kappa)=\frac{I_{n/2}(\kappa)}{I_{n/2-1}(\kappa)}$$
is the maximum likelihood estimate of the concentration parameter $\kappa$. $r$ is in $[0,1)$, the range of $A_n(\kappa)$ for $\kappa\in[0,\infty)$. $I_n(x)$ is the modified first-kind Bessel function.

I wrote an [Observable notebook](https://observablehq.com/@parcly-taxel/full-circle-at-the-von-mises) on the von Mises–Fisher, including a section on parameter estimation. [Sra (2011)](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.186.1887) gives several ways of computing $A_n^{-1}$ and I used Newton's method in the notebook, but before that I tried using series expansions, which led me to the question below.

Despite $\lim_{r\to1^-}A_n^{-1}(r)=+\infty$, numerical calculations show that the absolute error of Banerjee *et al.*'s approximation (given in the Sra paper)
$$A_n^{-1}(r)\approx\frac{r(n-r^2)}{1-r^2}=B_n(r)$$
is *uniformly bounded* over $[0,1)$ for *all* $n\ge2$, with
$$\lim_{r\to1^-}(A_n^{-1}(r)-B_n(r))=-\frac12$$
independent of $n$.

> How can this last limit be shown rigorously?

It would be nice if an exact series expansion of $A_n^{-1}(r)$ about $r=1$ can be obtained to prove the limit immediately. By series reversion it is easy to get expansions about $r=0$, e.g.
$$A_2^{-1}(r)=2x+x^3+\frac{5x^5}6+\frac{19x^7}{24}+\frac{143x^9}{180}+\cdots$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $r$ is close to $1$, $\kappa$ is large and positive. Hence, one has to use the large-$\kappa$ asymptotics of the modified Bessel function (cf. [$(10.40.1)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.40.E1)). In this way, we get
$$
r = 1 - \frac{{n - 1}}{{2\kappa }} + \frac{{(n - 1)(n - 3)}}{{8\kappa ^2 }} + \frac{{(n - 1)(n - 3)}}{{8\kappa ^3 }} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{\kappa ^4 }}} \right).
$$
Inversion and algebraic manipulation yields
\begin{align*}
\kappa  & = \frac{{n - 1}}{{2(1 - r)}} + \frac{{3 - n}}{4} + \mathcal{O}((1 - r)) \\ & = \frac{{r(n - r^2 )}}{{1 - r^2 }} - \frac{{2(r - 1)^2  + 6(r - 1) + (5 - n)}}{{2(r + 1)}} + \frac{{3 - n}}{4} + \mathcal{O}((1 - r)) \\ & = \frac{{r(n - r^2 )}}{{1 - r^2 }} - \frac{1}{2} + \mathcal{O}((1 - r)),
\end{align*}
which is the desired result.

Comment: Well, I never checked out A&S or the DLMF for years. Congratulations.